# Monotype Hadassah font doesn't display correctly under win 7

Tags: windows-7, truetype, word-2013

i recently installed fresh win 7 pro OS on brand new DELL i5 desktop machine. while trying to use word 2013, i noticed that text written in **Monotype Hadassah** font is displayed using **Times new roman** font.
is anybody noticed such an issue?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some experiments:

- the fonts works OK in notepad - which means that probably the problem is in office 2013 and not in the OS itself.
- since the font is registered as restricted with respect to the "embedding" ability i thought that it may be due to this restriction, but nevertheless, removing the restriction ( i recommend on [TTFPatch utility](http://www.derwok.de/downloads/ttfpatch/) didn't change the behaviour.
- interestingly, i found that saving the document as PDF resulted in correct rendering of the 
  font - which is pretty satisfactory to me.